# /dev/port vs /dev/mem

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, parallel-port

I need some clarification.  I can directly write to `/dev/port` to get direct access to a parallel port and it works fine (I can turn on LEDs plugged into the port connector).  However, I thought I could do the same with `/dev/mem`? (http://tldp.org/LDP/khg/HyperNews/get/devices/fake.html).  When I try to read and write to `/dev/mem` I get no errors, but the writes never seem to be reflected on the external connector.  I ask just because this isn't what I expected based on what I've read about writing to `/dev/mem`.

Can you not access ioports via `/dev/mem`?

Comment: IO ports and memory are different address spaces. Where are you writing? The linked example is about VGA. Notice that VGA uses IO address space for control registers and memory address space for the framebuffer.

Comment: @ninjalj: not necessarily. In DOS you can in fact do `*(unsigned short far *)0x400` to peek around the COM ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throwing in a handful of suggestions (untested). It could be that...

- Writing to memory position 0x378 directly requires being in real mode to have the desired effect (since it may be remapped in Protected Mode).
- The use of `/dev/mem` requires that the hardware has been MMIO-mapped, and you also need to know the MMIO address (which usually is not 0x378).

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: this only applies to x86 processors (and perhaps a few others).

Memory-mapped I/O is not quite the same as port I/O on x86 processors.

jørgensen is right in that memory is remapped in protected mode - however, I/O ports cannot be remapped in this manner. `/dev/port` refers directly to the I/O ports, whereas `/dev/mem` maps to (I believe) physical ram (i.e. NOT remapped), so in this case, you want to use `/dev/port`.

As for the link you provided, it uses `/dev/mem` for memory-mapped I/O (again, not the same as I/O ports).